# How to display a recyclerView inside another recyclerView with the following JSON response

Tags: android, json, android-layout, listview, android-recyclerview

Using `RecyclerView` inside another `RecyclerView` is a bad practice as being said in many forums. So I couldn't figure out how to display the results of the following `JSON` array. The `JSON` response has an array inside another `JSON` array. If I could use a `recyclerView` inside another `recyclerView` then how to do that. Please help.

```
{
"status": 1,
"sData": {
    "Order Deatils": [
        {
            "orderId": "FFEDOD20170624651D7A49696DBB2B4EE38DD1B8257A1972587100",
            "time": "2017-06-24 18:02:16",
            "total": "280",
            "staus": 0,
            "deliveryStaus": "pending",
            "Fish Details": [
                {
                    "product_id": 1,
                    "qty": 500,
                    "product_price": 80,
                    "product_img2": "9767994334steakslice.jpg"
                },
                {
                    "product_id": 3,
                    "qty": 500,
                    "product_price": 60,
                    "product_img2": "9767994482sol.jpg"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "orderId": "FFEDOD20170624526989C7BB6A872E68F6CF2433F7F93023644600",
            "time": "2017-06-24 18:35:46",
            "total": "130",
            "staus": 0,
            "deliveryStaus": "pending",
            "Fish Details": [
                {
                    "product_id": 4,
                    "qty": 500,
                    "product_price": 65,
                    "product_img2": "9767997426Rupchanda-Fish.jpg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"eData": {
    "eCode": null
}
}
```

Comment: I know how to convert a JSON response to POJO class. My issue is how to display such response in my UI. Need all your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this.

- Create two layout files (`my_layout_file.xml`, `my_recycler_view_content.xml`)
- Inside `my_layout_file.xml`, add a recyclerView tag (`first_recycler_view_id`)
- Inside `my_recycler_view_content.xml`, add another recyclerView tag (`second_recycler_view_id`)
- Create an adapter `RecyclerViewAdapter`
- Inside `RecyclerViewAdapter`, you can load view like this: `View myView = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_recycler_view_content, null)`
- Then you can get the second recycler view: `RecyclerView mySecondRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) myView.findViewById(R.id.second_recycler_view_id)`
- Inside your Activity, you can load your first recyclerView: `RecyclerView myFirstRecyclerView =
  (RecyclerView)findViewById(R.id.first_recycler_view_id)`
- Then you can set your `RecyclerViewAdapter` in `myFirstRecyclerView` : `myFirstRecyclerView.setAdapter(new RecyclerViewAdapter(context))`
- Inside your second recycler view (`mySecondRecyclerView`) you can display your result.

Comment: You can also create another adapter for your second recycler view to display you result

Comment: Thank you for the help. Please upvote my question if you don't mind. 

Answer (score 0):

You could convert json array into pojo class , for this use this site
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/

then display it on recyclerview

Comment: I don't have any issue regarding the JSON converting to POJO. My issue is how could i display such type of result in my android app. I thought to use a recyclerview inside another recyclerview but that seems to too complicated as seen in many stack overflow questions

Answer (score 0):

I would have used ExpandableListView with groupView having your Order details and childView having your product details. Also make ExpandableListView to be always expanded.

Use different POJO for Order and Product details and Order POJO must have ArrayList of Product POJO.